Maven clean install creates big cache under ".clean"
So I have a maven multi-module project in the structure:

my-project-parent

my-project-component1

my-project-component2

...

my-project-componentX




When I run mvn clean install -Pmyprofile1,myprofile2 inside my-project-parent maven says:
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ norcap-parent ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\..\my-project-parent\target 
.. however what it does instead is that it moves everything from the target directories of each my-project-componentX + what was previously in the .clean directory inside \my-project-parent\target\.clean
As consequence, the \my-project-parent\target\.clean grows exponentially (46 GB at the time of writing)
Does anyone know why I get this behavior and how can I prevent it?
NB: I can share relevant parts of the POM if needed, just don't know which ones would they are atm
Maven version: 3.9.3
Java version:
openjdk 11.0.21 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.21.9.1 (build 11.0.21+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.21.9.1 (build 11.0.21+9-LTS, mixed mode)

Expected result:
target  directory in parent project to be cleaned
Actual result:
target  directory has cached contents of old target directories

The directory target/.clean of size 46 GiB is redicously large... please first remove that completely... and share the pom file...
